# Jenkins Conditional steps not completing shell script

Tags: bash, jenkins, conditional-statements

OK, so I've been asked to allow a "safe word" in our Git commit comments so that our CI build will skip if the developer wants to just commit without building.  So, I set up a Conditional Step (multiple) with Execute shell in the Run? field.  I'm running the following command to see if the safe word is in the commit message and if it is, "Don't run" the build and if it's not, to run the build.  If I put a header in this shell (i.e. #!/bin/bash), I get an error.  Without it, my script stops after setting the RUN variable.  The IF..THEN..ELSE loop doesn't even begin to run.  Here's my script..

```
RUN=$(git --no-pager log -1 --pretty=online:"%s" --grep "keyword")
if [ "$RUN" != "" ];
    then exit 0
else
    exit 666
fi
```

The output when the "safe word" is not present looks like this:

```
++ git --no-pager log -1 --pretty=online:%s --grep blech
+ RUN=
Run condition [Execute Shell] preventing perform for step [BuilderChain]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

With the "safe word" present, the output is this:

```
++ git --no-pager log -1 --pretty=online:%s --grep initializer
+ RUN='online:CVirtualBroker  - Tweak construction to use initializer lists - 
Run condition [Execute Shell] preventing perform for step [BuilderChain]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Notice that the RUN variable gets set, then the script stops.  What gives?

AJ

Comment: Was the command beforce `if` failed?

Comment: No, the RUN=$(command) is evaluating appropriately (check second output).  If I run and echo command before the RUN=$(command) it works, but everything after the RUN=$(command) just gets skipped.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

you have a semicolon at the end of If statement

**if [ "$RUN" != "" ];**

which make it stop...

The command after is **exit 0** so I assume that your process stops